# Do i have to host my web site on Azure Hosting or use App Services to Use Azure Media Services?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Is there a limitation like that or can i use their media services from anywhere? I looked up but couldn't find enough information about this.

I want to upload videos in a web project and then displaying them on pages.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more details like how are you planning on using Media Services.

Comment: To upload videos on a web project and then displaying them

Answer (score 0):

There is **no need to host** complete web application on azure to get media services. But it is **suggestable to host** the site on azure. Because to cover the latency.

Host the website or application wherever you need and create media service on azure. Upload videos on the platform and tag the specific video **URL's and Credentials** to your app service and connect it to existing azure services. That will connect the videos to the specific location in the web page.